# renaming a two part package name to a three part one

Tags: android

how to change an app's package name in android studio from two part name to three part. like:

```
Mycompany.Myapp
```

to

```
Mydomain.Mycompany.Myapp
```

I know how to rename three part package name to three part package name but I'm not sure how to add a part to app's package name so make a two part to a three part.

Comment: Note that some namespaces cannot be renamed after you upload your app to the Play Store, or it will be recognized as a different app.

Comment: if you want to change package name of your application  juts go to the app gradle fiel and change it there  .. thats it

Comment: but keep @PeterBruins instructions in notice